# How do I resolve error message: "Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option"

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android development and I'm currently building
my first real app. I'm trying to implement a MVVM architecture
and because of that I'm having a viewModel for each fragment and
each viewModel has a viewModelFactory. At least, this is how I
understood it has to be.

I use the boilerplate code everyone seems to use for the factory:

```kotlin
class ExampleViewModelFactory(private val exampleDao: ExampleDao) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(exampleViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return ExampleViewModel(exampleDao) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, that the compiler is giving me the following error:

> e: C:\Users\ ...\ExampleViewModel.kt: (64, 7): Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option

And this error is produced by the viewModelFactory class I have implemented in the viewModel. I really can't tell what this means and I cant find anything helpful or even related to my specific problem. I basically followed some basic tutorials about creating your first app, but I keep on running into errors like this. In most cases, I was able to fix the problem by myself, but this time it's different.

I know that a lot of you have a lot of experience and knowledge, so I hope that some of you find the time to help me and give me a hint what I can do to fix this.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It seems like you are either directly or indirectly (through some other library) depending on [Lifecycle `2.5.0-alpha01`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.5.0-alpha01).

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217593040):

> You need to temporarily add following to your `build.gradle`:
>
> ```
> tasks.withType(KotlinCompile).configureEach {
>     kotlinOptions {
>         freeCompilerArgs += [
>                 "-Xjvm-default=all",
>         ]
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Note that in certain circumstances you may want to use `all-compatibility` instead of `all`, learn more about that in [Jebrain's blogpost](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-1-4-m3-generating-default-methods-in-interfaces/).
>
> Starting with kotlin 1.6.20 you won't need touch build.gradle for more information see [KT-47000](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47000)

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and helpfull answer. I'll take a look into the blogpost you've provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for this answer since last 3 days.

Comment: If you use `KotlinComplie` and got error you can use `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile`

Comment: you save my life , but should the question is "Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option" just remove the error message i cant resolve" for better on people searching, i able found when go to make question only not on goolge.  and put the text on body/question.

Comment: in which build.gradle should i add this?

Comment: @ShoaibKhalid module's build.gradle

Comment: Where inside of `build.gradle` did you add this code? I've tried multiple options such as appending to the end of the file, within `android`, etc. but I still receive an error. I have also tried @ChiragSavsani solution.

Comment: @TedLavender instead onf `tasks.withType(KotlinCompile).configureEach {` 
Use `tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {`

Comment: Would it be really bad practice to extend ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory instead of implementing ViewModelProvider.Factory ?

Comment: ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory can be used as well instead of ViewModelProvider.Factory

Answer (score 22):

**Update;** If you use `1.6.20` version of Kotlin,
then changing `build.gradle` is NOT required.

Old answer:

Try putting these line inside of android{} block in module build.gradle file

```
 kotlinOptions{
    freeCompilerArgs += [
            "-Xjvm-default=all",
    ]
}
```

If above code doesn't work try adding these below lines inside dependencies{} block

```
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach{
    kotlinOptions{
        freeCompilerArgs +=["-Xjvm-default=all",]
    }
}
```

Comment: The first one fixed it, thanks :)

Comment: The first one fixed it for me.

Comment: @RohitSingla It's better to update the kotlin version though.

Answer (score 8):

Kotlin version (kts) of @ianhanniballake's answer

```kotlin
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile::class).configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + "-Xjvm-default=all"
    }
}
```

Comment: Should either of these statements be added to the end of `build.gradle` or is there a specific section of the file ie `android` or `dependencies` that it should be placed within? I receive an error when adding the code and syncing: `org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method withType() for arguments`

Answer (score 1):

Use the stable version, in this case 2.4.1.
I have the same problem and I solved it by making this change.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was in kotlin libraries version

I was using in build.gradle:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10
```

and in build.gradle (app) [for Java compatibility]:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10"
```

then I create a common kotlin_version variable in ext:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    ...
    kotlin_version='1.7.10'
  } ...
```

and use for both (each in respective place):

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you override the create fun of `ViewModelProvider.Factory` avoid the question mark after vieModel

Incorrect:

```
<T : ViewModel?>
```

Correct:

```
< T : ViewModel>
```

Seems like there where some changes in the class.

Answer (score 0):

use theses dependencies in your gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix with navigation 2.4.1 version