# Implementing ViewModelProvider.Factory fails with Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' after adding Android Jetpack Compose navigation lib

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I had this simple viewmodel provider factory code (borrowed from one of Google's code samples), which happily obliged and compiled perfectly...

```
fun <VM : ViewModel> viewModelProviderFactoryOf(
    create: () -> VM
): ViewModelProvider.Factory = SimpleFactory(create)


private class SimpleFactory<VM : ViewModel>(
    private val create: () -> VM
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val vm = create()
        if (modelClass.isInstance(vm)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return vm as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Can not create ViewModel for class: $modelClass")
    }
}
```

... Until i introduced this library:

> implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.0-rc02"

Now all of a sudden compilation fails with:

**Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option**

(error pointing to *: ViewModelProvider.Factory* )

Why? What did navigation bring in with it? (I did confirm 100% it's the navigation lib causing it, remove it, and the error is gone)

Note: Q is not about how to solve it, compiler suggests it clearly, adding these args - freeCompilerArgs +=  "-Xjvm-default=all". The Q is about why this is happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve error message: "Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992947/how-do-i-resolve-error-message-inheritance-from-an-interface-with-jvmdefault)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, found it. The problem is that bringing in compose navigation, version 2.5.0-rc also updates androidx.lifecycle to 2.5.0-rc (from, in my case, 2.3.0), and in there, they changed the ***Factory interface*** by adding a method with implementation (and also adding implementation to the existing method in the interface).

Compare:

Factory implementation before 2.5.0:

```
public interface Factory {
        /**
         * Creates a new instance of the given {@code Class}.
         * <p>
         *
         * @param modelClass a {@code Class} whose instance is requested
         * @param <T>        The type parameter for the ViewModel.
         * @return a newly created ViewModel
         */
        @NonNull
        <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass);
    }
```

Note one method, *create*, **without implementation.**

Here is the rewrite they did in 2.5.0

```
public interface Factory {
        /**
         * Creates a new instance of the given `Class`.
         *
         * Default implementation throws [UnsupportedOperationException].
         *
         * @param modelClass a `Class` whose instance is requested
         * @return a newly created ViewModel
         */
        public fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            throw UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Factory.create(String) is unsupported.  This Factory requires " +
                    "`CreationExtras` to be passed into `create` method."
            )
        }

        /**
         * Creates a new instance of the given `Class`.
         *
         * @param modelClass a `Class` whose instance is requested
         * @param extras an additional information for this creation request
         * @return a newly created ViewModel
         */
        public fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>, extras: CreationExtras): T =
            create(modelClass)

       
          ...
        }
```

So that explains it, this interface is now a *default implementation interface*, and to inherit from it, need to add the compiler args, as suggested by the compiler (freeCompilerArgs +=  "-Xjvm-default=all").

Answer (score 3):

We encountered this also when we added compose libraries. We solved it by adding the `xjvm-default` option to our gradle file.

```
android {
  kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs +=  "-Xjvm-default=all"
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, the compiler suggests just that, the question is not how to solve it, but why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

first, upgrade all of your [fragment](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.5.0) and [activity](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.5.0) dependencies to `1.5.0` and your [lifecycle dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.5.0) to `2.5.0`. by doing so, your activities and fragments can handle the `creationExtras` part without requiring you to do anything. then in your factory method, replace this line:

```kotlin
//replace this line
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
//with this one
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>, extras: CreationExtras): T {
```

and you are good to go. source: [These extras are provided automatically by your Activity or Fragment when using Activity 1.5.0 and Fragment 1.5.0, respectively.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.5.0:%7E:text=These%20extras%20are%20provided%20automatically%20by%20your%20Activity%20or%20Fragment%20when%20using%20Activity%201.5.0%20and%20Fragment%201.5.0%2C%20respectively.)

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me

```
val viewModel: ViewModel by viewModels(
        ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() }, 
        factoryProducer = { VMFactory }
)
```